# Intellij Idea Ultimate shortcuts in UML

Tags: ide, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying IDEA Ultimate, but I have a problem on UML Diagrams View, I just cannot add things via shortcuts, but only with mouse.
For example, if within the UML window I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (should add a new class according to Idea 8 tutorial) nothing happens, plus I have noticed that when I rightclick with the mouse on "add", the word "class" got no shortcuts on its right side. 
I am using Linux on kernel 3.0 wich XFCE as desktop manager.
Previously i had a problem with "-" (minus) key which I resolved by changing keymap to something else, but this doesn't solve my new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same shortcuts work as in the **Project View** and **Navigation Bar**. In the default keymap it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> for the **New** action that will show the pop-up with choices.

Comment: Weird, Alt+Insert isn't working. I also checked in keymap menu by pressing em in "search for keys" and it doesn't answers (it does with Alt + Stamp, which is Alt + FN + ins). Could it be related to my Linux ? On Eclipse everything is working fine anyways. About the original problem i wasn't clear. I Meant that when i rightclick with mouse on a diagram , it appears new and add class, but there are no relative shortcuts shown (as they are in the tutorial i followed for idea8) and corresponding keys aren't working.. thanks!

Comment: i found an image that worths more than my words. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/80/uml1.png That's the thing i am missing, i have only names (like "Class") but i don't have the assigned shortcuts on the right side, and obviously i can't use them! thanks in advance

Comment: `Settings` | `Keymap` | `Main Menu` | `File` | `New...`, use the shortcut listed there for pop-up menu. There are no individual shortcuts for Class/Interface/Enum in the recent IDEA version.

Comment: Oh, they removed individual shortcuts? Damn, those were avaiable at least in version "8", how unlucky! I think i should ask on their forums then! Thank you for everything!

Comment: You don't need to copy your question in the forum, JetBrains reads and answers here. Consider submitting a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA instead.